# Parallellize bash scripts and conditional interruption

Tags: bash

I've seen many questions about parallelizing bash scripts but so far I haven't found one that answer my questions.

I have a bash script that runs two python scripts sequentially (the fact that are python script is not important though, it could be any other bash job):

```
python script_1.py
python script_2.py
```

Now, assume that script_1.py takes a certain (unknown) time to finish, while script_2.py has an infinite loop in it.

I'd like to run the two scripts in parallel, and when script_1.py finishes the execution I'd like to kill script_2.py as well.

Note that I'm not interested in doing this within the python scripts, but I'm interested to do this from a bash point of view.

What I thought was to create 2 "sub" bash scripts: bash_1.sh and bash_2.sh, and to run them in parallel from a main_bash.sh script that looks like:

```
bash_1.sh & bash_2.sh
```

where each bash_i.sh job runs a script_i.py script.

However, this wouldn't terminate the second infinite loop once the first one is done.
Is there a way of doing this, adding some sort of condition that kills one script when the other one is done?

As an additional (less important) point, I'd be interested in monitoring the terminal output
of the first script, but not of the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler than you think. When `bash_2.sh` finishes, just kill `bash_1.sh`. The trick is getting the process id that `kill` will need to do this.

```
bash_2.sh &
b2_pid=$!
bash_1.sh
kill $b2_pid
```

You can also use job control, if enabled.

```
bash_2.sh &
bash_1.sh
kill %%
```

Note that you don't need bash script for this; you can run your Python scripts directly in the same fashion:

```
python script_2.py &
python script_1.py
kill %%
```

Comment: I think it's the other way round: kill second python script when the first one terminates.

Comment: @chepner thanks! Say that I need to run the non-infinite loop first, would your solution be: bash_1.sh &
bash_2.sh
b2_pid=$!
kill $b2_pid

Comment: Updated; I got confused by your attempt, which swapped the roles of the two scripts. The one with the infinite loop goes in the background; the one that terminates eventually is left in the foreground.

Comment: ok, I think it makes sense to me now.  And I guess the foreground one is the second one (after the &) and it's the one that "prints the outputs to terminal", right?

Comment: Well, both jobs will print to the terminal, as they both have the same standard output. The main difference is that only the current foreground job can use the terminal for standard *input*. (A background job that tries to read from the terminal will be stopped until you can put it into the foreground and resume.)

Answer (score 5):

If your scripts need to start in that sequence, you could `wait` for the `bash_1` to finish:

```
bash_1 &
b1=$!
bash_2 &
b2=$!
wait $b1
kill $b2
```

Comment: does wait here waits for the first script to be finished or just waits for tits execution to start?

Comment: `wait` waits for the process to terminate. See `man bash`.

Comment: ok so just to make sure I understand (sorry, bash is quite new to me): bash_1 and bash_2 run in the background while wait $b1 runs in the foreground: when bash_1 finishes also wait $b1 finishes and the foreground moves to the next command which is kill $b2, killing bash_2 , right?

Comment: No. Both `bash_1` and `bash_2` keep on running in the background. the "foreground" script then waits for `bash_1` to terminate. And then it continues and kills `bash_2`.

Comment: ok I think it's what I meant, I should have used "wait $b1" to make the comment more readable, as the way it reads now I see how it could have been misleading :) thanks for the explanation